# add multiple files and commit different message to each one

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-commit

After the `git add .`, how can I give different commit messages to each file? If I submit multiple files with the same commit message, then how I change the commit message for each one? I tried `git--amend` but the default editor is confusing me.

From a repository with multiple files, how I can get a specific file? I tried:

```
git remote add filename <url from repository>
git fetch filename
git merge filename/master
```

But I got all the files from the repository.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3IUN.png)

Comment: in other words what IMSop says: for each file do `git add filename` followed by `git commit`. git commit --ammend` is used if you want to add/change files to the latest commit or change the commit message

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't work with versions of individual files - every commit is a snapshot of your entire project. You don't commit individual files, or check out individual files, you commit or check out a whole commit - a whole snapshot of the project.

When you run "git add" you are telling git what content of particular files to include in the next snapshot you commit. In particular, "git add ." means "include everything in the current directory as it currently is in the next commit I make"; "git add somefile.txt" means "include the current content of sonefile.txt in the next commit I make". Files that you don't include in this way will have the same content they had in the previous commit.

The text editor that pops up doesn't have any control over what's in the commit, it's just the way the command line tools ask for the commit message. All the control over what goes into the commit is in the "git add" command.